# MYSQL ¿Como hago un trigger para actualizar stock despues de anular una factura?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Quiero que después de anular un registro en la tabla tblingreso se actualice el stock correspondiente en la tabla articulos (se reste el stock):

```
 UPDATE tblingreso SET estado='Anulado' WHERE idingreso='1';
```

Tengo mi tabla **tblingreso** con los campos:

```
 idIngreso   int(11)
 idProveedor int(11)
 total  decimal(14,4)
 estado varchar(20)
```

Con datos sería así:

[image: Tabla de cabecera de ingreso con datos:]

La tabla de detalle **tbldetalleingreso:**

```
 iddetalleingreso int(11)
 idingreso int(11)
 idarticulo int(11)
 cantidad int(11)
 preciocompra decimal(14,4)
```

Con datos la tbldetalleingreso:

[image: Detalle con datos]

y la tabla **tblarticulo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD:He intentado de la siguiente manera y NO he podido crear el trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_updStockAnular After update on tblingreso for each row 
begin
update tblarticulo SET stock = stock - new.tbldetalleingreso.cantidad
where tblarticulo.idarticulo=new.tbldetalleingreso.idarticulo;
end
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los 2 problemas que veo con el trigger son:

1. `new.tbldetalleingreso.xxx`: No puedes usar esta expresión para acceder a la información de la tabla `tbldetalleingreso`. Usando el keyword `new`, solo tienes acceso a las columnas de la tabla `tblingreso`.
2. No tienes el punto y coma después del `end`: `end;`

Para poder poner al día el stock en la tabla `tblarticulo` usando a la vez la información de la tabla `tbldetalleingreso`, necesitas hacer un join en el `UPDATE`:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_updStockAnular after update on tblingreso for each row 
begin
  update tblarticulo a
    join tbldetalleingreso di
      on di.idarticulo = a.idarticulo
     and di.idingreso = new.idingreso
     set a.stock = a.stock - di.cantidad;
end;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Exacto! Muchas Gracias